# React Native Scrollview analogue Android

Tags: android, reactjs, scroll, webview, native

I am new to React Native. Currently running project that requires a WebView component.

But the main page of the app is too long (WebView is at the bottom of the page). So the user should scroll down to the WebView section.

And then scroll event should be intercepted by WebView block.

iOS is good for me.

Android prevents WebView to intercept scroll from parent ScrollView. I have read lots of articles and stack posts on this issue.

I am not Java developer, so instead of hooking Java I suppose maybe I am doing something wrong in terms of layout components choose?

Maybe I should something else instead of parent ScrollView?

But how can I scroll down the page then?

**[UPDATE]** I actually did a trick with setting webview fixed height. But in this case (when have a lot of content in webview) the performance is dropped at horizontal scrolling.

I've changes ScrollView on FlatList. In theory, this component should not render the whole data of the block, only visible content. But this helped me only with vertical scrolling. Still have issues with horizontal scrolling (no issues if the WebView component has small fixed height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result I run Android app on my real device (Nexus 6P) and it worked without any performance drop. Probably it's the issue of Android Studio simulator.

Anyway I think using FlatList instead of ScrollView helped me there.

Just set real content height to a WebView content, so it's not required to vertically scroll it.